# A complete proof of the Lagrange multipliers theorem using the implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

While searching on MSE, I couldn't find a complete rigorous proof the method of Lagrange multipliers using the implicit function theorem. I tried to write a complete proof myself below, but am not sure about some details, mainly the reordering of coordinates part. Any advice is very appreciated.

**Theorem.** Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ and $h:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be continuously differentiable functions, $C\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and $M=\{h=C\}$. Assume that $\text{rank } h'(x)=n$ for all $x\in M$. If $f$ attains a constrained local extremum at $a$, subject to the constraint $h(a)=C$, then there exists $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\nabla f(a)=\lambda_1\nabla h_1(a)+\dots+\lambda_n\nabla h_n(a), \quad \quad (1)$$

where $\nabla f(a)=[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} (a),\dots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_d} (a)]^\top$ and $\nabla h_i(a)=[\frac{\partial h_i}{\partial x_1} (a),\dots,\frac{\partial h_i}{\partial x_d} (a)]^\top$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

**Proof.** Suppose $f$ attains a contrained local extremum at $a$. First note that $h'(a)=[\nabla h_1(a),\dots, \nabla h_n(a)]^\top$ is $n\times d$, and so $\text{rank } h'(x)=n$ implies that $n\leq d$ and that $h'(a)$ has $n$ linearly independent columns. If $n=d$, then $h'(a)$ is invertible, and we can write $f'(a)=\Lambda h'(a)$ with $\Lambda:=f'(a)[h'(a)]^{-1}:=[\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n]$. Transposing gives $(1)$. Hence assume WLOG that $n<d$.

Next we claim that we can assume WLOG that the first $n$ columns of $h'(a)$ are linearly independent. Otherwise there exists a permutation $\pi:\{1,\dots,d\}\to \{1,\dots,d\} $ that reorders the columns of $h'(a)$ so that it holds. Define  $f^*:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ and $h^*:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^n$ by

$$f^*(x_1,\dots,x_d)=f(x_{\pi^{-1}(1)},\dots,x_{\pi^{-1}(d)}), \quad h^*(x_1,\dots,x_d)=h(x_{\pi^{-1}(1)},\dots,x_{\pi^{-1}(d)})$$

Then we have

$$\frac{\partial f^*}{\partial x_j}(x_1,\dots,x_d)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{\pi(j)}}(x_{\pi^{-1}(1)},\dots,x_{\pi^{-1}(d)}) \quad 1\leq j\leq d,$$

$$\frac{\partial h_i^*}{\partial x_j}(x_1,\dots,x_d)=\frac{\partial h_i}{\partial x_{\pi(j)}}(x_{\pi^{-1}(1)},\dots,x_{\pi^{-1}(d)}) \quad 1\leq i\leq n, \quad 1\leq j\leq d$$

and so the continuous differentiability of $f,h$ implies the continuous differentiability of $f^*,h^*$. Let $a^*=(a_{\pi(1)},\dots,a_{\pi(n)})$. Then

$$\frac{\partial f^*}{\partial x_j}(a^*)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{\pi(j)}}(a) \quad 1\leq j\leq d,$$
$$\frac{\partial h_i^*}{\partial x_j}(a^*)=\frac{\partial h_i}{\partial x_{\pi(j)}}(a)  \quad 1\leq i\leq n, \quad 1\leq j\leq d$$

It follows that the columns of $f^{*'}(a^*)$ and $h^{*'}(a^*)$ are those of $f'(a)$ and $h'(a)$ permuted according to $\pi$. Moreover we see that $f^*$ attains a  constrained local extrumum at $a^*$, subject to the constraint $h^*(a^*)=C$. Since condition $(1)$ for $f,h$ at $a$ is equivalent to condition $(1)$ for $f^*,h^*$ at $a^*$, we have reduced the problem to the case where the first $n$ columns of $h'(a)$ are linearly independent.

As a last reduction, we may assume WLOG that $C=0$, for otherwise we can replace $h$ by $h-C$.

Let $m=d-n$ and denote points in $\mathbb{R}^d=\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ by $(x,y)$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$. Then $h$ satisfies  the conditions of the implicit function theorem at the point $a=(a_x,a_y)$, as found in Rudin PMA Theorem 9.27 for example. Therefore, there exists open sets $U\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$  and $W\subset \mathbb R^m$ with $(a_x,a_y)\in U$ and $a_y\in W$, and a continuously differentiable function $g:W\to\mathbb R^n$ such that $g(a_y)=a_x$ and $h(g(y),y)=0$ for all $y\in W$. In particular we have

$$\{(g(y),y):y\in W\}\subset M \quad \quad (2)$$

Define the function $F:W\to \mathbb R$ by $F(y)=f(g(y),y)$. This functions is differentiable on $W$, and the chain rule gives $F'(y)=f'(g(y),y)\begin{bmatrix} g'(y)\\ I_m \end{bmatrix}$. Since $a_y\in W$ and $g$ is continuous at $a_y$, it follows from $(2)$ that $F$ has an unconstrained local extremum at $a_y$. For if there exists an $r>0$ such that $f|_{M\cap B_r(a)}$ has an unconstrained extremum at $a$, then by choosing $\delta>0$ sufficiently small we obtain $(g(y),y)\in M\cap B_r(a)$ whenever $y\in W\cap B_{\delta}(a_y)$. Using the fact that the derivative must vanish at a local extremum, and partitioning $f'(a)=[f_x'(a) \quad f_y'(a)]$, we get

$$0=F'(a_y)=[f_x'(a) \quad f_y'(a)]\begin{bmatrix} g'(a_y)\\ I_m \end{bmatrix}=f_x'(a)g'(a_y)+ f_y'(a)  \quad \quad (3)$$

Next consider the function $H:W\to\mathbb R^{n+m}$ defined by $H(y)=h(g(y),y)$. This functions is differentiable on $W$, and the chain rule gives $H'(y)=h'(g(y),y)\begin{bmatrix} g'(y)\\ I_m \end{bmatrix}$. Moreover we have $H=0$ by definition of $g$, and so in particular

$$0=H'(a_y)=[h_x'(a) \quad h_y'(a)]\begin{bmatrix} g'(a_y)\\ I_m \end{bmatrix}=h_x'(a)g'(a_y)+ h_y'(a) \quad \quad (4)$$

where we partioned $h'(a)=[h_x'(a) \quad h_y'(a)]$. Since the first $n$ columns of $h'(a)$ are linearly independent, $h_x'(a)$ is invertible, and from $(4)$ we get

$$g'(a_y)=-[h_x'(a)]^{-1}h_y'(a) \quad \quad (5)$$

Substituting $(5)$ in $(3)$ and solving for $f_y'(a) $ we obtain

$$f_y'(a) =\Lambda h_y'(a) \quad \quad (6)$$

where $\Lambda:=f_x'(a)[h_x'(a)]^{-1}:=[\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n]$. But we also have

$$f'_x(a)=f'_x(a)[h_x'(a)]^{-1}h_x'(a)=\Lambda h_x'(a) \quad \quad (7)$$

so combining $(6)$ and $(7)$ gives

$$f'(a)=[f'_x(a) \quad f'_y(a)]=\Lambda [h_x'(a)\quad  h_y'(a)]=\Lambda h'(a)$$

Transposing gives $(1)$, as desired.

Comment: All this is standard material in optimization theory. See for example  Ward Cheney's Analysis for applied mathematics, where this problem is treated in the slightly more general case of Banach spaces and constrains are of the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker type (equalities may be replace by inequalities). Luenberger's nonlinear optimization book deals with the problem in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and also provides second order conditions to determine maxima or minimum.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you for the references. Am mostly unsure about the change of coordinates part. The notes I read do not provide the details about this. Do you think its ok?

Comment: The steps seem all right. The book of Tom Apostol also handles this problem in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $m$ constrains  $m\leq n$ through the  implicit function theorem. You may want to check that book.

Comment: Another textbook to be aware of is [Numerical Optimization](https://www.amazon.com/Numerical-Optimization-Operations-Financial-Engineering/dp/0387303030) by Nocedal and Wright. I believe it has a good discussion of this.

Comment: @littleO Thank you for the reference! Did you have time to read my proof? Is it ok?